# Full grid canvas in Apple Number

Tags: mac, iwork-numbers, page-numbers, iwork

Apple Number have a default blank canvas shaped as a sheet with margins.
Is it possible to change the default blank canvas to an endless grid like Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's impossible.